# Blackbox exporter probe_ssl_earliest_cert_expiry giving wrong value in grafna

Tags: grafana, prometheus-blackbox-exporter

I have installed blackbox exporter to monitor application url and SSL expiry

In grafana dashboard , I see the SSL expiry is showing wrong

probe_ssl_earliest_cert_expiry{instance=~"$target"} -time()

Please advise

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "SSL expiry is showing wrong", what value does "probe_ssl_earliest_cert_expiry{instance=~"$target"}" return for example.